# How to add .swf file in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to add an animation in  starting screen of my game. I did that animation in flash. how to load it in cocos2d

Answer (score 4):

Don't think you're going to be able to do this.  Flash has never been able to run on the iPhone/iPod and very likely never will at least for the foreseeable future.  Someone would have to write a custom SWF file loader and player specifically for Cocos (no small task).  Even then I doubt Apple would allow such an application to be approved.  I would suggest converting your SWF to an iPhone/iPod compatible movie format.  QuickTime (mov) for sure is supported, mpg and avi may work as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is and will be no Flash support on the iPhone. You'd have to to convert the animation into single images and use cocos2d's animation system.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you wanted four years ago has released! It's called [GAF](http://gafmedia.com) This is library and a converter for flash animations.